# Application session timeOut in cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Hi friends i'm developing MAC desktop application using cocoa. I want to add session time out for in the app. Example my application running in background user dont touch and do nothing in app. After 20(we need to set) app will return home page(login page) for session time out.

Will help me how to set session in cocoa application

Comment: What is exactly the problem you're having?

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom NSApplication class and override sendEvent:. Something like this:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [super sendEvent:event];

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(applicationSessionTimeout:) object:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(applicationSessionTimeout:) withObject:self afterDelay:SESSION_TIMEOUT];
}
```

Basically all mouse and keyboard events enter your app through this method. You just need to override it to set your timers.

Comment: This helped me. I did need to change the object in the line `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(applicationSessionTimeout:) object:nil]` from `nil` to `self` to get it working.